# 【Githubのレポジトリの慣習】各branchの役割/説明は一般的に行わないのかどうか

Tags: github

Github初学者です。
各branchの役割/説明はREADME.mdなどで一般的に行わないのでしょうか。
（Githubのレポジトリの慣習に関わる部分だと思います。）

色々なリポジトリを眺めていると
ブランチ名からどんなブランチかはっきり分からないものが多々あります。
それらの殆どは改修用ブランチであることは何となくわかるのですが、
それが分からない人もいると思いますし、
cloneしたい際に知らずのうちに作業用ブランチに切り替えてしまって、
cloneしてしまったみたいなケースも想定できます。
そう考えると、ブランチの説明をどこかで行うのが親切なのではと思うのですが、
一般的にはブランチの説明は行わないのでしょうか。

長くなってしまいましたが、よろしくお願いいたします。

**前提認識**
・branchは作業場所で、バージョン管理はタグで行うのが一般的である。
・リモートbranchには最新版を状態を保ったmainブランチや、作業中のdevelopブランチなどがある。
・各バージョンの更新内容は、"releases"の説明欄やREADME.mdのreleaseトピック、
　RELEASE.mdで説明するのが一般的。
・閲覧者がデータをダウンロードしたい場合は、
　多くは"releases"や"タグ", mainブランチでのcloneやzipのダウンロードを行う。

Comment: 前提知識をもう少し掘り下げさせていただきますが、gitのブランチモデル(githubFlow gitflow)はご存じですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
"A successful git branching model"に関しては調べたことがありましたが、
その２つは聞いたことがありませんでした。
今調べた所、gitFlowがまさにA successful git branching modelで、
githubFlowは簡略版なのですね。

Answer (score 1):

複数ユーザーで共通のリモートリポジトリに直接プッシュするようなケースでは確かにブランチの運用ルールをすり合わせる必要がありそうですが、GitHub は基本的にオーナー自身、および許可されたユーザーしか書き込むことができません。

ローカルリポジトリやフォークしたリポジトリ内で作業する分には自由なブランチ名を使えばいいので、第三者向けの説明をする必要が無いのではないでしょうか。

一方で、プルリクエストを受ける際に「main ブランチではなく develop など指定のブランチにプルリクエストを送ってください」といった説明書きはよく見かけます。

Comment: 拙い質問にご回答ありがとうございます。

閲覧者がローカルリポジトリやフォークリポジトリで作業する際に、フォークやcloneを行うと思います。
その際に各ブランチの説明があった方がどのブランチをcloneするのがよいかなど分かりやすいのかなと思ったのです。

個人的にそう思ったのならすればいいじゃんというのはそうなのですが、それが一般的でない訳が何かあるのかなと思いまして質問致しました。